# How console.log(object) works in background?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I have this code:

```
const obj = {name: 'maro', age: 77}

console.log(obj); // it logs { name: 'maro', age: 77 }
```

It seems like evident! but I want to know how console.log internally works ? which methods of "obj" it calls to get the "{ name: 'maro', age: 77 }"

obj contains those properties:

```
obj.__defineGetter__      obj.__defineSetter__      obj.__lookupGetter__      obj.__lookupSetter__      obj.__proto__             obj.constructor           obj.hasOwnProperty
obj.isPrototypeOf         obj.propertyIsEnumerable  obj.toLocaleString        obj.toString              obj.valueOf    obj.age        obj.name
```

But none of them returns "{ name: 'maro', age: 77 }"!

even  `obj.toString()` returns `'[object Object]'`

Comment: `propertyIsEnumerable` and the rest are inherited and not *own* properties of the object. You need to expand the `__proto__` to see the properties inherited from  `Object.prototype`

Comment: yeah, I want to know which properties console.log use to print the object

Comment: It displays *own* properties of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [Node.js `console.log` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args), it uses, behind the scenes, [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) to format its output.

According to [`util.format` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args), it returns a string representation of an object with generic JavaScript object formatting, similar to [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).

You can see its actual implementation, at least for **Node.js**, here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/75dc8938a40100a53323ed87159a1ab2f149ceca/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L1567. Have fun reading this code :)

Answer (score 2):

It is `obj.valueOf()` if I'm not mistaken. Here is the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Comment: but the return of valueOf is an object too

Comment: valueOf() returns primitive value of the specified object. And object is not a primitive value.

Comment: it returns an object for this example

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueOf().

```
const object1 = {name:"ankit",age:27}
console.log(object1.valueOf());
```

> Note: Objects in string contexts convert via the toString() method,
>   which is different from String objects converting to string primitives
>   using valueOf. All objects have a string conversion, if only "[object
>   type]". But many objects do not convert to number, boolean, or
>   function.

Comment: This didn't answer my question, I was asking about how console.log works. You can check the checked answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you need the name 'maro' and the age 77, you need use obj.name and obj.age...

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  The question was how to return ` "{ name: 'maro', age: 77 }"`

Comment: Sorry, my bad :/